# Fantasy book with a female protagonist in a wizard oppressed world that Comes into magic through a stone she picks

Tags: story-identification

Looking for an online novel I read a while back.

I believe it was set in a wizard oppressed medieval era.

The main protagonist is a girl who finds a stone and is somehow able to use magic.

On this being discovered, her family is forced to let her be taken away as an apprentice; however the warlock they put her with has a history of killing all his apprentices, hence their decision to send her there, in hopes she wouldn't survive.

On arrival, the warlock seals the magic in her stone and begins mistreating her.

At some point, she wishes to die but just before she dies, the warlock saves her, having fallen in love with her.

The magic system was one of ley lines / feeling the magic, then using it to help pull different strings/nodes to do different things. She changes the color of her dress the first time she realizes she can use magic without the stone, and even models a ring similar to the warlock's as her own "ring of power" and a sign of their union.

There was also a bit where their memories mix. The warlock, for some reason or other, cannot taste anything, but when they meld, he is able to tell how certain things taste from her memories and experience their taste through her memories. She in exchange got his centuries of fighting experience, rendering her a formidable fighting force, though this caused a bit of resentment as in his opinion she got the skills in an instant whereas he had weathered hundreds of wars and battles plus hours of training and discipline to attain them

They do have a son and one of the final scenes was her son sparring with a sword instructor who kept mistreating the son. She walked over, picked a sword, proceeded to give the male sword instructor the whooping of his life sparring-wise, then she took over her son's swordplay lessons after that.

Comment: This is a very good start!

Comment: I kinda want to read this now